# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR after migrating WordPress site to another site - attempting to create staging environment

Tags: wordpress, environment, staging

I have a site hosted on 1&1 Ionos hosting. Purchased an SSL for the site from 1&1 Ionos as well. So let's say https://www.business.com/ is what I have. Then I have another another site say http://www.mycompany.com/ hosted at the same place - still waiting for my business SSL to be approved hence the http.

So I exported the database from business.com using plugin WP Migrated DB - setting the new URL and actual filepath.

Then I imported the database into a new database for my staging environment to be hosted at http://www.mycompany.com/clients/business.

I copied ALL the wordpress files for the site http://www.business.com/ into http://www.mycompany.com/clients/business exactly except I changed wp_config.php file to reflect the new database details. i.e username, database, location and password.

So I expected http://www.mycompany.com/clients/business to be a complete replica of the original https://www.business.com/. But when I browse to http://www.mycompany.com/clients/business I get the following error:

*This site can’t provide a secure connection mycompany.com sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR*

I can't even login to the admin panel of http://www.mycompany.com/clients/business/wp-admin

Is what I tried even possible and if it is please tell me what I did wrong and how to fix it. I'd like to create a staging environment to test new themes and plugins before implementing on live environment. Critical to my original site is the aMember plugin which manages all the membership registration info. I've deleted the Really Simple SSL plugin folder from WP-Content/Plugins folder but the error remains.

Thanks in advance for any and all help and advice!

Comment: Did you check your .htaccess rules? Are you using a plugin that enforces HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
Check your .htaccess for rules enforcing https

Step 2:
Did you replace all links in the database? If not, you must search and replace all links from https://www.business.com/ to http://www.mycompany.com/ 
You can use a tool from: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/comment-page-4/

Or just use command line wpcli (wp search-replace https://www.business.com http://www.mycompany.com

Step 3:
Open the new 'http://www.mycompany.com/' in a incognito tab. Browser caching might still redirect you to https.

Comment: about step 2: just find and replace could brake a lot of informaion from website, just because they can be saved as serialized array

Comment: I've copied the exported the db again made sure to replace https with http. I also ran the tool from interconnectit but there was no https strings to replace. I also cleared my browser cache So now http://www.mycompany.com/clients/business opens the home page of https://www.business.com but when I click on any of the links to browse to other pages I get redirected to http://www.mycompany.com/clients/business/somepage with an error: "OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND.
It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?"

Comment: To fix the links I followed these instructions: Try flushing your mod_rewrite rules: Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks ;Save settings (no need to make any changes) - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14685/after-server-migration-only-the-homepage-works